# Removing the remainder of a line after occurrence of a character

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file with several thousand lines. What I would like to do is remove the first occurence of '|' in a line and all in that line that follows. I'm rather new to python and am not sure how one would go about this. re.search comes to mind but I am not sure how to only remove a portion of a line.

Comment: By "all in that line that follows" do you mean everything after the first `|`?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this:

```
>>> s = 'abc|123|xyz'
>>> s
'abc|123|xyz'
>>> s.split('|', 1)[0]
'abc'
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
>>> s[s.index('|')+1:]
'123|xyz'
```

It looks like this second method is slightly faster:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit as time
>>> time("s.split('|', 1)[0]", "s = 'abc|123|xyz'")
0.39399194717407227
>>> time("s[s.index('|')+1:]", "s = 'abc|123|xyz'")
0.2868010997772217
```

---

**Relevant Documentation:**

- [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: You should pass `1` as the optional second argument to `split()`, so that it won't bother looking for more delimiters once it finds the first one.